# How to put a space only between dt/dd in HTML definition lists?

Tags: html, css

I want to have dt/dd pairs aligned closely, but not touching each other. I have this now:

[image: form1]

Using this css:

```
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
dt {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
}
dd {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I want to have this:

[image: form2]

But whenever I use some tag like padding-right:5px or margin-right or margin... the dd part always goes to a new line, like this:

[image: form3]

I don't want a big padding all around the dt elements, all I want is to separate them from each respective dd. I want the distance between dt and dd to be bigger than the distance between two consecutive rows.

Comment: Could you add some HTML code with this as well? Try setting up a working example using https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: With the default box model, `padding` *adds* to the displayed width of an element. Either define you padding also in %, and make sure all widths and paddings dont add to more than 100%, or use `box-sizing: border-box;` on your `dl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to the dt element, so it will remain 30% width even if you add padding and borders

Just notice that 70% + 30% = 100%. If you add 30 pixels it will be > than 100%.

Basically with the property `box-sizing` set to `border-box` you say that the element must be that width, and then paddings and borders will be calculated from that width, and not added like with the default box-model